# onFling swipe up also triggers swipe left or swipe right

Tags: android, swipe, onfling

In my android app I am using `onFling()` method of <strike>`onTouchListener`</strike> `SimpleOnGestureListener` to detect swipe left, top, right, bottom.

Problem is, when I swipe up it also triggers swipe left or right.

I tried playing around with `SWIPE_THRESHOLD` value but it didn't make a difference even when I increased it to `5000` from `50`.

How can I make sure that only swipe up will be fired when I swipe top.

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener
{

public static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 50;
public static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 50;
protected GestureDetector gestureDetector;
final int IDLE = 0;
final int TOUCH = 1;
final int PINCH = 2;
int touchState;
double dist0, distCurrent;
private Context CONTEXT;

public OnSwipeTouchListener(Context ctx)
{
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
    CONTEXT = ctx;
}

public OnSwipeTouchListener() {

}

public void onSwipeRight()
{
}

public void onSwipeLeft()
{
}

public void onSwipeTop(float diffY)
{
}

public void onSwipeBottom(float diffY)
{
}


public void onDoubleTap(){

}

//    public abstract void onSwipeRight();
//
//    public abstract void onSwipeLeft() ;
//
//    public abstract void onSwipeTop(double diff) ;
//
//    public abstract void onSwipeBottom(double diff);
//
//    public abstract void onPinch(double distCurrent) ;
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
{
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}

private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener
{
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY)
    {
        boolean result = false;
        try
        {
            float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            if(Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY))
            {
                if(Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD)
                {
                    if(diffX > 0)
                    {
                        onSwipeRight();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        onSwipeLeft();
                    }
                }
                result = true;
            }
            else if(Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD)
            {
                if(diffY > 0)
                {
                    onSwipeBottom(diffY);
                }
                else
                {
                    onSwipeTop(diffY);
                }
                result = true;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;




    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        OnSwipeTouchListener.this.onDoubleTap();
        return super.onDoubleTap(e);
    }
}
}
```

EDIT : What I want to achieve is, when the user swipes up then swipe left or swipe right should not get fired/ called.(which are being called right now when I swipe up)

EDIT 2 : I have changed the `onFling()` method to just use velocities and upon debugging it seems its working correctly i.e. It does not fire `swipeLeft()` or `swipeRight()` when I `swipeTop()`

```
@Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, 
float velocityY)
    {
        boolean result = false;
        try
        {



            if(Math.abs(velocityX) > Math.abs(velocityY)){
                //Horizontal Swipe

                if(velocityX < 0){
                    //Swipe Left
                    onSwipeLeft();
                    result = true;
                }
                else if(velocityX > 0){
                    //Swipe Right
                    onSwipeRight();
                    result = true;
                }
            }
            else if(Math.abs(velocityY) > Math.abs(velocityX)){
                //Vertical Swipe

                if(velocityY < 0){
                    //Swipe Top
                    onSwipeTop(Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()));
                    result = true;
                }
                else if(velocityY > 0){
                    //Swipe Bottom
                    onSwipeBottom(Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()));
                    result = true;
                }
            }



        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;


    }
```

Now here is the problem.
I am using library `https://github.com/lsjwzh/RecyclerViewPager` and set `onTouchListener` with `GestureDetector` with above `onFling()` method. 
Even though I have set a custom `onTouchListener` it seems the `RecyclerViewPager` seems to be getting swipe commands/ gestures after the custom `onFling()` method.

I tried setting `recyclerViewPager.setOnFlingListener(null)` but it did not work.
How do I disable gestures being passed to recyclerViewPager after setting custom onTouchListener?

Comment: what do you need `diffX` and `diffY` for if you have both velocities passed to `onFling` method?

Comment: To check distance? Can  it be done with just velocities?

Comment: it is already done inside GestureDetector, see GestureDetector.java

Comment: @pskink i just saw.<strike>its an interface with 4 abstract methods? Or am I missing something?</strike> 
Edit: My bad. looking at it right now.

Comment: @pskink I didn't find anything particular in GestureDetector.java

Comment: if all you want to do is to check if its left, right, up or bottom fling use velocities

Comment: @pskink I can already check whether user is swiping left, right, top or bottom.

What I want to achieve is, when the user swipes up then swipe left or swipe right should not get fired/ called.(which are being called right now when I swipe up)

Comment: no, if you use velocities only one direction is detected

Comment: @pskink Velocities work fine as you said. thanks. But it seems even if the GestureDetector is working appropriately the underlying recyclerViewPager is getting swipe gestures. How do I avoid that. Added edit to main post.